# How to find the closest div with class by travesering down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here I am trying to traverse down and remove the nearest div with class `div2` but it is not working properly.

The issue is if I click the random cancel button for e.g click cancel button at last.

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".cancel", function () {
   $('.div').find('.div2').first().remove();
   $(this).closest('.div1').remove();
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
   <div class="div1">
   <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button> 
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
   <p>hello</p> 
   </div>

   <div class="div1">
   <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button> 
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
   <p>hello2</p> 
   </div>

   <div class="div1">
   <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button> 
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
   <p>hello3</p> 
   </div>

    <div class="div1">
   <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button> 
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
   <p>hello4</p> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rather do it this way, remove the div after the parent (the following div2), and then remove the parent (the div1)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".cancel", function() {
  let $_parent = $(this).parent();
  $_parent.next('div').remove();
  $_parent.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="div1">
    <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div1">
    <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>hello2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div1">
    <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>hello3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div1">
    <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>hello4</p>
  </div>

</div>
```